# How to use bootstrap popover with reactjs

Tags: javascript, reactjs, bootstrap-popover

I have tried to follow the bootstrap documentation to make work a popover. But I have been unsuccessful in converting this piece of code into something React can understand.

```
   {
  $(document).ready(function() {
    $('[data-toggle="popover"]').popover();
  });
}
```

Without it my popover cannot function properly. What's the solution?

Comment: Checkout reactstrap: https://reactstrap.github.io/components/popovers/

Comment: Or React-Bootstrap https://react-bootstrap.github.io/components/popovers/

Answer (score 3):

Also you can do that too, if you define jquery in index.html. 
Call jquery from window object.

```
componentDidMount() {
    window.$('[data-toggle="popover"]').popover();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

It make sense to use `react-bootstrap` library but if you still want a solution go ahead and follow this...

You need to understand react lifecycle methods instead of using `document.ready` callback function.

try adding this to your react component

```
componentDidMount() {
    $('[data-toggle="popover"]').popover();
}
```

Make sure you import jquery top of the file

```
import $ from 'jquery'
```